# How to handle transaction and rollback when persisting in two different data sources

Tags: spring-boot, distributed-transactions

I have a REST service which internally invokes (RestTemplate) two other services viz Service A and Service B.
Service A persists data into a LDAP store whereas Service B persists data to a database.
I am trying to understand the best approach to handle a transaction that spans across Service A and B.
If Service call A is success but B fails, I need to rollback the successful execution of A.

Comment: You should read about the SAGA pattern https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes this helps. "If a local transaction fails because it violates a business rule then the saga executes a series of compensating transactions that undo the changes that were made by the preceding local transactions." What if the compensating transaction fails?

Comment: Then you have a problem. You must retry or have some user to fix the problem